# Electron - How to prevent locking of the UI

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, electron, es6-promise

I have an app build with electron and on startup it does a large amount of API calls to setup the UI. This seems to render my UI unusable until it has all finished. I've read adding this code to the main process will have similar issues (lock up entire window). All the functions that make these API calls and save data to a vuex store return promises.

I've looked into creating child processes `require('child_process').fork('/worker.js'));` however I can't include my helper modules or classes from within those workers (SyntaxError: Unexpected token import).

What is the best way to do asynchronous work without blocking the UI, while still having access to my renderer classes and singletons?

This is the boilerplate I'm using if it helps https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/tree/master/template

Comment: can you provide context as to why there are API calls to render the UI? - (why not have render a standard UI for most common components and only use one API call for the User preferences that determine UI render?)

Comment: It's an internal desktop timer for JIRA, so it needs to make a lot of API calls to fetch projects, tasks in those projects, sync external worklogs etc

Comment: Initiate the API calls, return promises, and render the projects when the promises are resolved?

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment, the work done inside the promises is still locking the UI however

Comment: how long is the response for the first API call to return? (how about the other calls, and how long does it take for first render?)

Comment: Sorry rendering the general UI doesn't rely on the API calls, there are placeholders to show no data etc. However when the API calls are happening a side bar list of items ignores most of my clicks or adds a few seconds delay to transitioning the fact I've clicked on them

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was calling vuex commit very fast which is a synchronous action and was causing the rest of the application to lock up as a result

Comment: What was your solution? Fewer commits? What if that's not an option?